# Natural graphs that are not scale free

Tags: graph-theory, ni.networking-internet

It is now a well known observation that many graphical structures that arise in natural settings tend to obey scale-free properties, such as the power law of degree distribution.

Are there any good example of natural graphs that are fairly random and not do not necessarily obey scale-free properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The connections between neurons do not form scale-free networks, I think. See e.g. Figure 1 on p.181 of http://www.indiana.edu/~cortex/Koetter_chapter_modified.pdf and observe that the vertex degrees only span a single order of magnitude.

Answer (score 7):

The network topology of wireless ad hoc networks and wireless sensor networks are often captured by a random geometric graph. This means, picking random points in a planar domain, and connecting any two that are within a certain distance threshold. These graphs have Poisson degree distributions, even though they are quite different from the Erdos-Renyi random graphs, and they arise naturally as a network model.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not sure what you mean by "random", obvious natural non-scale-free graphs are the road networks.

Comment: Well, random in the sense that the vertices would come at random and attach to others following some (possibly hidden) probability distribution.

Comment: Actually, road networks *are* scale-free, when viewed appropriately. Obviously the natural representation isn't, since most intersection have degree at most 4 or sometimes 5 or rarely 6. But if you take the dual representation - a node for each road, and edge between them if the roads *ever* meet - you do get a scale-free network: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~treport/tr/05-10/RoadNetworks.pdf.